# Dired ignore directory local mode value

Tags: emacs, local-variables, dired

How can I have `dired` ignore any directory local value set for `mode`? It I set a `mode` in a `.dir-locals.el` file, the variables apply to `dired` as well, causing it to fail.

For example, with a directory structure as

```
$ tree -a
.
├── config.d
│   ├── 010-github
│   └── 020-mail
└── .dir-locals.el
```

And in the dir-locals

```
(("config.d"
  . ((nil . ((mode . ssh-config))))))
```

If I try to `dired-find-file` on config.d, I get an error. How can I tell dired to ignore a `mode` value in the `dir-local-variables-alist`?

Comment: Why would you want to set `mode` for the `nil` case?!  Don't do that.

Comment: because I want all the files in the directory to be in that mode...

Comment: Either target the original major modes specifically, or use `eval` to decide what to do.